# Inheritance with different parameter lists

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, parameters, subclass

I have a base class for a checkers game, and I want to subclass that to implement different tree search algorithms, minmax, alphabeta and so on.

So I have something like

```
public class Checkers {
    ....
    public void findBestMove(Board b, int depth) {
        for(mv:b.possibleMoves()) {
        ...
           score = evalNode(b.domove(mv), depth + 1)
        ...
        }
    }

    int evalNode(Board b, depth) {<insert recursive node eval algorithm here>}
}
```

which works for minmax.
For alphabeta, I need more parameters:

```
    public void findBestMove(Board b, int depth) {
        for(mv:b.possibleMoves()) {
        ...
           score = evalNode(b.domove(mv), depth + 1, -9999999, -maxval)
           maxval = max(score, maxval)
        ...
        }
    }
    int evalNode(Board b, depth, alpha, beta) {<insert recursive node eval algorithm here>}
```

While the basic logic of findBestMove is the same for all tree search methods (generating all possible moves, trying each move and passing it on to the eval function, returning the best move...), the only difference is the call to the evaluation function, which requires algorithm-specific parameters.

Can you think of any way to construct the findBestMove method so that I can use its basic logic (the move loop) in all subclasses, but have a different evalNode-call? It seems a waste to rewrite this in every subclass. Is it just my lack of imagination or is this just not possible?

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: Where are alpha and beta coming from, and what types are they?

Comment: Steve: those are integers that get passed along in the search up and down the stack. But could be another list for another tree search algo. Or a String array to hold the current best path... or whatever.

Comment: thx andrew, will refrain from that from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to introduce an interface:

```
interface NodeEvaluator {
    int evalNode(Board b, depth);
}
```

And give it two implementations of which the second one, will accept additional parameters:

```
class MinMaxNodeEvaluator implements NodeEvaluator {
    public int evalNode(Board b, depth) {
        // evaluate node using min/max appproach
    }
}

class AlphaBetaNodeEvaluator implements NodeEvaluator {
    private int maxVal;

    public AlphaBetaNodeEvaluator()
    {
        this.maxVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    public int evalNode(Board b, depth) {
        int currentScore = evalNode(b, depth, Integer.MIN_VALUE, -this.maxval);
        this.maxVal = max(currentScore , this.maxVal);
        return currentScore;
    }

    private int evalNode(Board b, int depth, int alpha, int beta) {
        //...
    }

}
```

And instances of particular node evaluators should be injected into your `Checkers` class appropriately.